# Matplotlib xticklabels showing years instead of months

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas series of months and matplotlib is plotting it well.

But the xticklabel is just showing the year.

How can I show months instead of year?

After suggested correction this is what happened

[new graph after corrections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4CBI.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom date formatter. The following will use worded months:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%B"))
```

Comment: Thanks Blackadar...but it didn´t worked. Can you help me ? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happened when you tried adding this line? I see you have another format="" argument already in that code, you could try replacing "%Y%m" with "%B".

Comment: Hi ! I pasted the result below as another question as I didnt know how to past it as a comment.... Thank you